# DRuid metadata is not having records and jobs in pending state

Tags: mysql, metadata, druid

Druid Mysql metadata not showing segments and Jobs in Pending State

I completed a druid cluster setup and metadata in mysql. All services are showing. BUt Segments is showing "0 segments". Data sources is also showing "0 data sources". Lookups showing "Lookups uninitialized"

When I load any data, at the end the job shows pending state and never changed. Also my mysql metadata is showing zero records in segments table. server segments table also has no records.

Kindly advice.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: All the logs on master, data and query nodes are not showing errors, except coordinator.log on the master.

Comment: Its error contents are shown below:

Comment: 2023-05-31T14:50:30,469 INFO [Coordinator-Exec--0] org.apache.druid.server.coordinator.duty.BalanceSegments - Metadata segments are not available. Cannot balance.
2023-05-31T14:50:30,469 INFO [Coordinator-Exec--0] org.apache.druid.server.coordinator.duty.EmitClusterStatsAndMetrics - Load Queues:
2023-05-31T14:50:30,469 INFO [Coordinator-Exec--0] org.apache.druid.server.coordinator.duty.EmitClusterStatsAndMetrics - Server[10.1.41.97:8085, historical, _default_tier] has 0 left to load, 0 left to drop, 0 served, 0 bytes queued, 0 bytes served.

Comment: 2023-05-31T14:50:32,110 INFO [org.apache.druid.metadata.SqlSegmentsMetadataManager-Exec--0] org.apache.druid.metadata.SqlSegmentsMetadataManager - No segments found in the database!
2023-05-31T14:50:35,401 INFO [TaskQueue-StorageSync] org.apache.druid.indexing.overlord.TaskQueue - Synced 2 tasks from storage (0 tasks added, 0 tasks removed).

Comment: Also my mysql metadata tables: (segments, datasource) do not have any records

Comment: I fill its expecting to see data inside the metadata segments as the error above shows: "Metadata segments are not available. Cannot balance."

Comment: Are you seeing segment files in your deep storage location? Do the ingestion jobs succeed?

Comment: The ingestion jobs is submitting successfully. But all the jobs are in hanging or runing state. And never completing.

Comment: Are you seeing segment files in your deep storage location?

Comment: Segments table is showing no records. As per the storage location, these are the directories in my sub storage location. /u01/apache-druid-25.0.0/var/druid:

Comment: derby.log
metadata.db
segment-cache
task

Comment: This is the definition for my storage location:  druid.storage.storageDirectory=var/druid/segments . I am missing anything?

Comment: Sounds like the tasks are unable to publish segments. What is your druid.storage.type? Publishing means that the ingestion task writes the segment files it produced to [Deep Storage](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/dependencies/deep-storage.html) and after succeeding the overlord will write records to the metadata DB. You could have a problem in either of those.

Comment: Also, have you looked at the ingestion task log to see if any errors are reported there?